# PHP Float Number puzzle

Tags: php

How do i code below question in PHP ?

To print the curve data to the screen by positioning it with spaces, within a display area 51 chars wide.

You have the following 39 floats as source data.

```
14686.744, 14687.067, 14687.363, 14687.633, 14687.958, 14688.257,
14688.530, 14688.777, 14688.997, 14689.209, 14689.419, 14689.614, 
14689.792, 14689.928, 14690.047, 14690.526, 14691.351, 14692.560, 
14693.897, 14695.045, 14696.147, 14697.109, 14697.708, 14697.563,
14696.793, 14696.089, 14695.254, 14694.135, 14693.018, 14691.445, 
14689.647, 14688.055, 14686.720, 14685.607, 14684.638, 14683.800,
14683.081, 14682.794, 14682.572
```

Notes:

- The differences between floats is very small.
- Strip away the minimum value and only display the variance between highest and lowest values.
- Space the values to fill the display area of 51 chars wide.
- Echo the row number at the start of each line.
- The correct output looks like this:

**OUTPUT**

```
0               .
1                .
2                 .
3                  .
4                   .
5                    .
6                     .
7                     .
8                      .
9                       .
10                       .
11                        .
12                        .
13                         .
14                          .
15                             .
16                                 .
17                                     .
18                                         .
19                                            .
20                                                .
21                                                  .
22                                                 .
23                                               .
24                                            .
25                                          .
26                                      .
27                                  .
28                             .
29                       .
30                  .
31              .
32          .
33       .
34    .
35  .
36 .
37.
38.
```

Comment: this i show output looks http://prodota.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=177745&st=8700

Comment: Any efforts so far? Right now it looks like "Hey, I have this homework. Please, do it for me".

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like:
Convert the numbers to percentages, so the lowest float = 0 and the highest = 100.

then take each percentage as a percentage of the width (which is 51). Eg. with 10% would be "51 * 0.10 = 5.1". Make it an int (floor) and call it spacing (perhaps you need to subtract 1 from the value.).

Then print as many spaces as defined by "spacing" and append the dot + newline.